# Could not import settings. Import by name is not supported

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have a Python 2.7/Django 1.4 project. I'm running Ubuntu 11. The project structure has a root folder of Notecard, a project named Notecard, and an app named Notecards:

```
notecard/

-- notecard/

-- -- manage.py

-- -- settings.py

-- -- __init__.py

-- -- urls.py

-- -- notecards/

-- -- app2/
```

I'm running Linux, and the path to the root folder is `/home/dan/notecard/

My PYTHONPATH variable is:

```
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
['', '/home/dan/notecard', '/home/dan', '/home/dan/notecard/notecard/settings']
```

My DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is:

```
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'].split(os.pathsep)
['notecard.settings', '/home/dan/notecard/settings', '/home/dan/notecard/notecard/settings']
```

And my Manage.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "notecard.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I use PyCharm as my IDE, and when I try to run the dev server I get the following:

> ImportError: Could not import settings 'notecard.settings' (Is it on
>   sys.path?): No module named notecard.settings

My settings are all correct in the Django Support section of Pycharm.

When I try to run the dev server directly from the terminal I get:

> ImportError: Could not import settings
>   'notecard.settings:/home/dan/notecard/settings:/home/dan/notecard/notecard/settings'
>   (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.

From the terminal, it seems to be picking up multiple environmental variables. I'm not sure why - I thought it should take one that matches.

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to get this working - preferably through Pycharm, but hopefully in general.

I've obviously tried adding all of the environmental variables, verifying the Pycharm settings and verifying my manage.py system variable info as well (just in case.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable not in your actual OS environment, but rather in your PyCharm environment?  Try doing that.

Comment: Do you really have Settings.py with the capital S? The Linux file system is case sensitive; it won't be able to import 'settings' if you have 'Settings.py' on your disk.

Comment: All of the folders and files were lowercase, my apologies - I've edited the post. Jdotjdot - I changed the `PYTHONPATH` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variables inside of Pycharm and now I simply get "Import by filename is not supported". No other information. My Pycharm `PYTHONPATH` is `/home/dan/notecard`, and my Pycharm `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is `notecard.settings`. I do not use specific file names ie `settings.py` in the environmental variables or anywhere in my settings file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble, as the error message says, is your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. Why do you have multiple values for that? It needs to just be a single value: a module path. In your case it should probably be `notecard.settings`.

Comment: Changing the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the environmental variable in Linux (outside of Pycharm) to only notecard.settings results in this:
`ImportError: Could not import settings 'notecard.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named notecard.settings`

Comment: Actually, I see what part of the issue is. My environmental variable assignments are not sticking in Linux. If I assign the variables - `PYTHONPATH` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in the shell, they stay assigned for that shell only. Open another shell and they are gone. However, if they are assigned the error above goes away and I am left with `Import by filename is not supported` - The same error I get in PyCharm with the advice above.

Comment: In addition to the above, I had an `INSTALLED APP` listed with a /.. not sure why. Thanks

Comment: Dan, how about exporting those variables, like export VARNAME=value ?